# Reducing time complexity of an algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

This is a task taken from codility, which requires O(n) complexity. Although I've solved the task that it gives correct results, the time complexity is O(n*n). Would appreciate any help in explaining how to reduce that complexity to O(n).

> Task description:
>
> A non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given.
>   Array A represents numbers on a tape.
>
> Any integer P, such that 0 < P < N, splits this tape into two
>   non-empty parts: A[0], A[1], ..., A[P − 1] and A[P], A[P + 1], ...,
>   A[N − 1].
>
> The difference between the two parts is the value of: |(A[0] + A[1] +
>   ... + A[P − 1]) − (A[P] + A[P + 1] + ... + A[N − 1])|
>
> In other words, it is the absolute difference between the sum of the
>   first part and the sum of the second part.
>
> For example, consider array A such that:
>
> A[0] = 3   A[1] = 1   A[2] = 2   A[3] = 4   A[4] = 3
>
> We can split this tape in four places:
>
> ```
>     P = 1, difference = |3 − 10| = 7
>     P = 2, difference = |4 − 9| = 5
>     P = 3, difference = |6 − 7| = 1
>     P = 4, difference = |10 − 3| = 7
> ```
>
> Write a function:
>
> ```
> int solution(vector<int> &A);
> ```
>
> that, given a non-empty zero-indexed array A of N integers, returns
>   the minimal difference that can be achieved.
>
> For example, given:
>
> A[0] = 3   A[1] = 1   A[2] = 2   A[3] = 4   A[4] = 3
>
> the function should return 1, as explained above.
>
> Assume that:
>
> ```
>     N is an integer within the range [2..100,000];
>     each element of array A is an integer within the range [−1,000..1,000].
> ```
>
> Complexity:
>
> ```
>     expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);
>     expected worst-case space complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).
> ```
>
> Elements of input arrays can be modified.

```
My solution:  
int solution(vector<int>& A)
{
    // write your code in C++11
    int result = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    int part_1 = 0;
    int part_2 = 0;
    for (auto beg = A.cbegin(), end = A.cend(); beg != prev(end); ++beg)
    { 
        part_1 = accumulate(A.cbegin(),beg + 1,0);
        part_2 = accumulate(beg + 1,end,0);
        int current_result = abs(part_1 - part_2);
        if (current_result < result)
        {
            result = current_result;
        }

    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I think there's a small error in the task - it says "0 < P < N" but then uses an example in which P = N = 4 is used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let `S[i] = sum of the first i elements`. You can compute this with a single for loop:

```
S[0] = A[0]
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
  S[i] = S[i - 1] + A[i]
```

Then, for each index `0 < i < n`, the sum up until `i - 1` is simply `S[i - 1]`. The sum from `i` to the end of the array is `S[n - 1] - S[i - 1]`:

```
S[n - 1] = A[0] + ... + A[n - 1]
S[i - 1] = A[0] + ... + A[i - 1]

0 < i < n

S[n - 1] - S[i - 1] =  A[0] + ... + A[i - 1] + A[i] + ... + A[n - 1] -
                      (A[0] + ... + A[i - 1])
                    = A[i] + ... + A[n - 1]
```

After computing `S`, run another loop and check the differences between the two sums, which are computed in `O(1)` like I described:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
{
  sum_left = S[i - 1]
  sum_right = S[n - 1] - S[i - 1]

  // see if |sum_left - sum_right| is better than what you have so far
}
```

The time complexity is `O(n)` because you only run two for loops in which you only do `O(1)` operations at each iteration. The memory complexity is `O(n)` because you have to store `S`, which is the same size as your input.

Declaring `S` as `int[n]` should be fine judging by the assumptions we're allowed to make.

Comment: Memory complexity may be reduced to `O(1)` by updating `sum_left` and `sumright` with `+=`/`-=` `A[i]` (instead of using `S`).

Comment: @IVlad, Hi, thanks for your answer. About the computing of the sum of i elements, wouldn't it be better to use std::accumulate to do it?

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando in my original solution, you need access to all the partial sums. `std::accumulate` returns one sum, but you need access to the sum of the first `i` elements for each `i`. Or you can use `std:accumulate` to compute the sum of the entire array and then use @Jarod42's optimization for using `O(1)` memory.

Comment: @IVlad another thing is that they specifically said use c++11, and what you've proposed is at best C++98.  How would you address that issue?

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando C is a subset of C++11, so there is no issue. What I proposed only uses basic language elements: for loops, int variables and arrays. If you must use C++ elements, you can use `std::vector` instead of arrays. Other than that and `std::accumulate` for the optimal solution, there's really not much else to do.

Comment: @IVlad Hi, yet another thing, you are saying that the second loop where you are summing up sum_left and sum_right, you're saying that this is done in O(1) but I'd argue that that loop runs in O(N) and only sums are calculated in O(1). Would that be correct?

Comment: @IVlad Hi, I want to thank you for your excellent answer. Thank man!

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando you're welcome! Yes, the entire loop runs in `O(n)`, only the sums are calculated in `O(1)`. The entire thing is still `O(n)`, sorry if that wasn't clear.