# How do I optimise TapeEquilibrium solution for large arrays and make it pass all test cases C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization

I'm working through codility challanges via C++.

The TapeEquilibrium challange is outlined as follows.

> A non-empty array A consisting of N integers is given. Array A represents numbers on a tape.
>
> Any integer `P`, such that `0 < P < N`, splits this tape into two
>   non-empty parts: `A[0], A[1], ..., A[P − 1]` and `A[P], A[P + 1], ..., A[N − 1]`.
>
> The difference between the two parts is the value of:
>
> ```
> |(A[0] + A[1] + ... + A[P − 1]) − (A[P] + A[P + 1] + ... + A[N − 1])|
> ```
>
> In other words, it is the absolute difference between the sum of the
>   first part and the sum of the second part.
>
> For example, consider array `A` such that:
>
> ```
> A[0] = 3   A[1] = 1   A[2] = 2   A[3] = 4   A[4] = 3
> ```
>
> We can split this tape in four places:
>
> ```
> P = 1, difference = |3 − 10| = 7    P = 2, difference = |4 − 9| = 5 
> P = 3, difference = |6 − 7| = 1     P = 4, difference = |10 − 3| = 7
> ```
>
> **Write a function:**
>
> ```
> int solution(vector<int> &A);
> ```
>
> that, given a non-empty array `A` of `N` integers, returns the **minimal
>   difference** that can be achieved.
>
> For example, given:
>
> ```
> A[0] = 3   A[1] = 1   A[2] = 2   A[3] = 4   A[4] = 3
> ```
>
> the function should return 1, as explained above.
>
> Write an **efficient algorithm** for the following assumptions:
>
> `N` is an integer within the range `[2..100,000]`; each element of array `A` is an integer within the range `[−1,000..1,000]`.

My C++ solution is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <numeric>
#include <cmath>
// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// cout << "this is a debug message" << endl;

int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    // write your code in C++14 (g++ 6.2.0)
    if(A.size()==2)
        return std::abs(A[0] -A[1]);

    vector<int> head;
    vector<int> tail;
    int minDiff = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

    for(auto itr = A.begin(); itr != A.end(); itr++)
    {
        head.push_back(*itr);
        tail = vector<int>(itr+1, A.end());
        int headSum = std::accumulate(head.begin(), head.end(), 0);
        int tailSum = std::accumulate(tail.begin(), tail.end(), 0);
        minDiff = std::min(std::abs(headSum-tailSum), minDiff);
    }

    return minDiff;
}
```

The test cases for this solution:

[image: test cases for the above solution]

It's clear that this solution fails when it approaches large sequences. However, given that his solution is O(n); why does it struggle with large vectors and what can I do to optimise this solution?

Also, I have no clue what the "small elements" test cases are testing as the problem description does not mention floats or doubles.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my previous case wasn't O(n) at all. I've implemented a solution based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31785475/reducing-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm?rq=1) post's solution presented by user IVlad.

The code looks like this:

```
// you can use includes, for example:
// #include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <numeric>
#include <limits>
// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// cout << "this is a debug message" << endl;

int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    // write your code in C++14 (g++ 6.2.0)
    auto B = A;
    int difference = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

    if(A.size() == 2)
        return std::abs(A[0]-A[1]);
    for(uint i = 1; i < A.size(); i++)
        B[i] = B[i-1]+A[i];

    for(uint i = 0; i < A.size()-1; i++)
    {
        int headSum = B[i];
        int tailSum = B[A.size()-1]-B[i];
        difference = std::min(std::abs(headSum-tailSum), difference);
    }
    return difference;
}
```

The codility test cases for this algorithm.

[image: codility test cases]

Answer (score 0):

This one is also 100% 0(N)

```
int solution(vector<int> &A) {
// write your code in C++14 (g++ 6.2.0)
int totalSum = 0;
int firstSum = A[0];
for(unsigned int i=1;i<A.size();i++)    totalSum += A[i]; 
int min = abs(firstSum-totalSum);
for(unsigned int i=1;i<A.size()-1;i++){
    firstSum+=A[i];
    totalSum-=A[i];
    if(abs(firstSum-totalSum)<min) 
        min = abs(firstSum-totalSum);
}
return min;
}
```